# How to run 'sbt testOnly' for test sources in non-standard location?

Tags: scala, sbt

According to the documentation http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html the test sources should be in the standard location.  I am using a project that has the tests in a different location and when I run `sbt ~testOnly testspackage.*Spec` it doesn't run any tests.

How can I specify a different location to the testOnly task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tests are in a different location (in my case they were IT tests) the solution is to run `sbt it:testOnly <class>`.

Answer (score 2):

You must be in sbt context first before executing the commands. Try the following steps:

```
sbt
testOnly testspackage.*Spec
```

Comment: It worked for me. Do you *sbt* at the root level of the project?